# How to read a file present in application server using External tables

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, external-tables

How to read a file present in application server using external tables. I can't place the file in DB server as we are restricted from DB server.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm), the data file for an external file must be visible to the server.

You access an external file via a `DIRECTORY` object in the database, which points to a directory on the db server.

Now, you can mount a drive so that it appears in the file system, but someone with access to the db server will probably have to do that.